# M2M100Tokenizer.from_pretrained 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: huggingface-transformers, nonetype, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I have the following chunk of code from this [link](https://huggingface.co/facebook/m2m100_418M):

```
from transformers import M2M100ForConditionalGeneration, M2M100Tokenizer

hi_text = "जीवन एक चॉकलेट बॉक्स की तरह है।"
chinese_text = "生活就像一盒巧克力。"

model = M2M100ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/m2m100_418M")
tokenizer = M2M100Tokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/m2m100_418M")
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-c56f34229c4a> in <module>()
      5 
      6 model = M2M100ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/m2m100_418M")
----> 7 tokenizer = M2M100Tokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/m2m100_418M")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm using Google Colab, but funnily enough it works perfectly fine in VSCode.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Okay, traceback error included.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, it works fine in my local env but not on colab, I fixed this by using transformers==4.16.0 instead of the latest version, it was chosen arbitrarily however, it may work with a more recent one